# Get count by multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

this is my data and I need the result with the fastest way.

[image]

Comment: @PouriaSharif, post what you've tried.

Comment: NO ONE CAN ANSWER THIS QUESTION :-( since no one can tell you what is the fastest solution in your specific database, without getting more information from you! Please remember! the same query might behave differently on two different server. Moreover! even on the same INSTANCE of the SQL Server the same query might behave differently on two different databases!!! In order to find the best solution we need you to post DDL+DML. till then people can give you solutions, BUT NO ONE CAN TELL WHICH SOLUTION IS BEST FOR YOU

Comment: Please post DDL+DML. that mean that we need the queries that create the table and the relevant elements like indexes, relation to other tables, and please post queries to insert sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standart conditional aggregation:

```
select city,
       sum(case when active = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) active,
       sum(case when blacklist = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) blacklist,
       sum(case when license = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) license,
       sum(case when married = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) married
from TableName
group by city
```

Answer (score 3):

this gives output you are expecting

```
 declare @t table (code int,name varchar(10),Active varchar(5),Black varchar(5),License varchar(5),married varchar(5),city int)
    insert into @t (code,name,Active,Black,License,married,city)values (1,'john','true','false','true','true',1001),
    (2,'jack','true','true','true','fale',1002),
    (3,'sara','false','false','false','true',1001),
    (4,'shiela','true','false','false','false',1002)
    ;with cte as (
    select distinct city,
    CASE WHEN Active = 'true' then COUNT(ACTIVE)else NULL end ACTIVE,
    CASE WHEN Black = 'true' then COUNT(Black)else NULL end BLACK,
    CASE WHEN License = 'true' then COUNT(License)else NULL end License,
    CASE WHEN married = 'true' then COUNT(married)else NULL  end married from @t
    group by city,active,Black,License,married)
select DISTINCT city,COUNT(ACTIVE)[ACTIVE(*)],COUNT(Black)[Black(*)],COUNT(License)[License(*)],COUNT(married)[married(*)]  from cte 
GROUP BY CITY
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. I am using the fact that, count function does not count nulls.

```
Select City, 
COUNT(NULLIF(Active,'FALSE')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Blacklist,'FALSE')),
COUNT(NULLIF(License,'FALSE')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Married,'FALSE'))
From TableName
Group by City
```